# Could not find method compile() for arguments [file collection] on object

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, kudan

This image shows the project structure and the error

[image: img]

I'm following [this tutorial to build a sample app using Kudan](https://wiki.kudan.eu/Getting_started#Android).

Here I got an error (Shown in the screenshot) after step 5 (means after Adding kudanar.jar and cardboard.jar as file dependencies )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I see why you need a new module for `cardboard`. You can just place the `cardboard.jar` into `app/libs`, and in the `app/build.gradle`, you can compile that JAR file as well as any others with this one line

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: Thanks!
works fine after removing the cardboard and kudan module.
as you said i have added those .jar files into app/libs.
thanks again